# What kind of filter would produce this kind of frequency response?

Tags: frequency-response

What kind of filter would produce this kind of frequency response?

[image]

I'm pretty sure there's a moving average involved, maybe two, but that's as far as I got.

Comment: What do you mean by "what kind"? FIR or IIR, or do you need the exact filter coefficients, or something else?

Comment: Fair question.  I don't need anything precise, just want to understand filter structure could produce this pattern.  I hope that's somewhat clearer.

Comment: I suspect it is an FIR filter.

Comment: Yes, with its zeros on the unit circle, at least most of them.

Comment: Any more detailed insights? Let's pretend I want to replicate this in software...

Comment: In that case you'd need the filter coefficients. Or design an FIR filter satisfying the same specs, if you can figure out what they are.

Comment: Look into Blackman-Harris windows. Could very well be a moving average FIR with a Blackman-Harris window.